# How to prevent matrix from becoming list in R?

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe

Say I have a 2-by-3 matrix of zeros `A=matrix(0,2,3)` in R and another data frame with 2 columns, like `DF = data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,1),b=c(2,2,2,2))`. I would like to assign a row of the data frame to a column of the matrix, like `A[,1]=DF[4,]`. The problem is, this converts `A` to a list and completely throws the indexing of `A` off whack, presumably because of the different row numbering and column names of `DF`. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DF[4, ]` gives a one row data frame which is a list, while matrix is an atomic vector which can hold only one data type. You need to `unlist` the data frame row and convert it to an atomic vector before assigning it to the matrix:

```
A[,1] = unlist(DF[4,])

A
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    2    0    0
```